# get json string into php variables

Tags: php, json

I have the below code and what I am trying to do is get the json value from "total_reviews" into a php variable which we can call $total_reviews.

however what is happening is i am getting an error that says

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$total_reviews
```

Here is my code

```
//URL of targeted site  
$url = "https://api.yotpo.com/products/$appkey/467/bottomline";  
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($result);

echo "e<br />";
echo $data->total_reviews; 


// close curl resource, and free up system resources  
curl_close($ch);  
?>
```

If I print_r the result I have the below print out

```
{"status":{"code":200,"message":"OK"},"response":{"bottomline":{"average_score":4.2,"total_reviews":73}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the JSON data as an array then use the second parameter on `json_decode()` to make it convert the data to an array.

```
$data = json_decode($result, true);
```

If you want the JSON data as it was passed to you and I assume that is as an Object then use

```
$data = json_decode($result);

echo "<br />";
echo $data->total_reviews;
```

> The [`json_decode()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

But either way, if this is your JSON String,

```
{"status":
    {
        "code":200,
        "message":"OK"
    },
"response":
    {
        "bottomline":
            {
                "average_score":4.2,
                "total_reviews":73
            }
    }
}
```

then the `total_reviews` value would be

```
echo $data->response->bottomline->total_reviews;
```

or if you used parameter 2 to convert a perfectly good object into an array

```
echo $data['response']['bottomline']['total_reviews'];
```

Comment: Thank you Riggsfolly that helped

Comment: Totally my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode()` defaults to extracting into a stdClass object. If you want an array, pass a truthy value as the second argument:

```
$data = json_decode($result, true);
```

Comment: I just updating my code in the original post. however am getting an error that says Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$total_reviews